# Swift - Multiple Files Error: Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Bool'

Tags: swift, xcode

I understand to provide code for the error but this error `Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'Bool'` is for multiple files, even files that have no code just a class view controller declaration. Picture is provided of all the files affected. I am not sure how to debug this since clicking on the error does not provide the line of the error, only brings up the file. For some files when clicking on the error and bring up the file the error will disappear for that file then reappear.

[image]

Comment: Clean build folder, delete derived data, restart Xcode is some of the things that might help in a situation like this.

Comment: I've  have done what you have suggested, it didn't clear the errors. Other Swift developers I have spoken to have said there could be a missing curly brace } in some file. Which makes me think because usually when there is a missing curly brace in a file, the whole file gets filled with errors.

Comment: A missing brace in one file should not affect other files. But maybe search for places you return a Bool, or remove files from your target and re-build until the errors disappears

Comment: No that means that someone thinks the question isn’t clear or lacking research or similar. Stackoverflow has a voting system so that people can quickly give an opinion about a question or an answer.

Comment: Well then I would downvote Xcode because I can provide code for all those file but it would be a bit much. I’ve been searching but no luck yet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 func filterContent(searchText:String) {
    
    self.filteredUsers = self.usersArray.filter { user in
        
        let username = user!["businessName"] as? String
        
        return(username?.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
     
}
```

This code is where my errors had been coming from. This code was used in multiple files to sort users. This will throw this unfindable error in your code. This can cause errors to appear in files that don't even have code and when you tap on the error to show in file the error will disappear.

Comment: Could you explain how this code caused the error? This answer doesn't help others to debug the same error

Comment: It's the returned logic which is causing the error. So when this error appears, look at the return statements in your files.

Comment: Yes. It's a problem with the return value not matching indeed. I would update the answer to reflect this aspect better. Also, add that it seems a Swift 5.7 problem: https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/63137

Answer (score 5):

Try to find some place when you use "guard else { return }"

Maybe in some filter function.

Comment that place and try to build again.

If its build correctly then fix the "guard else" code.

I had same problem, and its helps me.

Comment: that would have been hard to catch. Thanks.

Comment: 1652 guard else { return } in my code. Hard to test :(

Comment: first of all, check the higher-order functions like .map or .filter etc. then try to find out in which of the commits the error appears

Comment: this answer saved me from wasting a lot of time. i should have returned a boolean value in the one of the guard let condition but i did forget and swift compiler went crazy. the only place that compiler did not give an error was the source of the error.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know the circumstances of your case. In my case it was a map function on a publisher that didn't return a Bool and was assigned to a variable.

Original failing line was

```
publisher.map({ result in
```

Changed with

```
publisher.map({ result -> Bool in
```

Answer (score 2):

Same here. It's weird, it's definitely a bug in Xcode. in my case problem was from this line:

```
var mainUrls: [String] = opts.map { if let u = $0.value ?? "" { return u } else { return } }
```

There should show error for return nothing in map closure, but instead in 24 files was showing:

`Cannot convert return expression of type '()' to return type 'String'`

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time this issue happens to me when I make a mistake inside `.map` or `.compactMap` functions. The easiest way for me to verify this is to copy the body of a function outside, comment `.map` or `.compactMap` calls and build. After this Xcode will highlight errors in your code and you will be able to resolve them. Hope that this will be helpful to someone.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, below is an example of how I got the error. context here is an NSManagedObjectContext. The problem here is the return without the Bool.

```
func a() -> Bool {
    return context.performAndWait {
        if (false) {
            return false
        }
        return
    }
}
```

For me the file with the error was one of the listed files and when building in the console it was the first file in the list och failed files.

Hopefully this will be helpful in some way in the search for your error.

Comment: How can I check which file is the first to be loaded instead of digging?

Comment: @LukasBimba When I did xcodebuild in the terminal, the file with the error was the first file listed in the error.